# Python C wrapper for reading variable argument lengths

Tags: python, swig, ctypes, cython, word-wrap

I am trying to replace MATLAB/MEX and switch to Python. I came across SWIG, ctypes & Cython as possible solutions and started trying out SWIG (which seems very simple).

My C functions have variable argument lengths of the form `main(int argc, char *argv[])`. I found solutions online, but getting this working with SWIG lead to a lot of issues.

1. Are the other methods (ctypes / Cython) any simpler?
2. Any example to do this task with SWIG will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually [an example in the SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_multi_argument_typemaps) for exactly this sort of function with Python. I've quoted it here with a minor change:

> ```
> %typemap(in) (int argc, char *argv[]) {
>   int i;
>   if (!PyList_Check($input)) {
>     PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expecting a list");
>     return NULL;
>   }
>   $1 = PyList_Size($input);
>   $2 = (char **) malloc(($1+1)*sizeof(char *));
>   for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
>     PyObject *s = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
>     if (!PyString_Check(s)) {
>         free($2);
>         PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "List items must be strings");
>         return NULL;
>     }
>     $2[i] = PyString_AsString(s);
>   }
>   $2[i] = 0;
> }
>
> %typemap(freearg) (int argc, char *argv[]) {
>    free($2); // If here is uneeded, free(NULL) is legal
> }
> ```

This allows you in Python to do simply:

```
import test
test.foo(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Where `test` is the name of the module you gave SWIG and `foo` is a function that matches the signature `int argc, char *argv[]`. Simple and intuitive to use for a Python programmer and it encapsulates and reuses the complex bit.

---

What the documentation doesn't seem to mention though is that there's an interface file that does all this for you already:

```
%module test

%include <argcargv.i>

%apply (int ARGC, char **ARGV) { (int argc, char *argv[]) }

void foo(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked perfectly! When I tried using the @HYRY's ctypes answer I'd get errors though. Would it be possible to use ctypes instead swig? I'm curious... :/

Comment: @BPL are you on a platform where `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(int)` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample by using ctypes.

First the c code, it must not change the content of argv:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(int n, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can call this c function by the following python code:

```
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("charpp_test.dll") 
argv = ["test1", "testtest2", "testtesttest3"]
dll.test(len(argv), (c_char_p*len(argv))(*argv))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, however, if I make any changes to the .c file and try the python code, the change doesn't reflect. I tried to "del dll" at the end of your code, but that doesn't help.

How do I unload this dll?